What does the IIS setting "Require SSL" do?
What is the effect of the check box setting in IIS:
"Require SSL"
when checked?
Does this enable HTTPS: protocol on a HTTP site?
Such that the website can be browsed with https: in the URL?
Does this allow only HTTPS: URLs?
Does it disallow HTTP: URLs on a web application?
I can't find any information about this checkbox if checked.


The only effect you get by checking that box is IIS immediately responding 403.4 responses to all HTTP requests to this site, and only HTTPS requests processed further.
There won't be anything else, such as automatically adding HTTPS binding to this site for you. You will have to do that on your own.
Therefore, people rarely use this setting nowaday due to bad user experience, but use URL rewrite rules to simply redirect end users from HTTP to HTTPS.

You won't find much information because this setting has been there for more than two decades now and such is assumed to be common knowledge.


It does exactly what it says: it makes it so that a connection requires SSL. You normally enable the SSL protocol by providing a certificate (or letting IIS auto-generate one) and telling IIS to provide access to your web site using port 443, the https: protocol, and the certificate. Clicking this box tells IIS that if it gets a port 80 connection, that it should reply with a redirect to the https: version of the site, rather than providing the site content unencrypted. You can do the same thing with more granularity using the .htaccess file, but this is somewhat easier.

This question is about IIS so a .htaccess file won’t be useful.  A web.config file will be though.

"Clicking this box tells IIS that if it gets a port 80 connection, that it should reply with a redirect to the https: version of the site" is completely wrong. IIS does no redirection in this case.

Fair. I don't know IIS very well at all apparently - my last experience with it was decades ago.

Enabling "Require SSL" ensures that all communication with the website must be encrypted using HTTPS. If it isn't correctly configured, it will fail.
